# Generate new iOS app distribution certificate from new MacBook

Tags: ios, keychain, apple-developer

I have an iOS app that is live in the app store, and I need to generate a new distribution certificate for signing the app. From what I understand, the app will always use the same private key, but needs a new certificate generated annually.

I am not using the same MacBook that I used to generate the original certificate, but I have the `.p12` file that was exported from the original MacBook. I have imported it into the `Keychain` and have been successfully signing releases of my app.

Now I need to know how to generate a new certificate from my private key. I tried right clicking on my private key in the `Keychain Access` app and selecting "Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority". Unfortunately this only resulted in the following cryptic message:

> "The specified item could not be found in the keychain"

How can I generate a new distribution certificate for my app?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried generating a new certificate through developer.apple.com? I'm talking about **both** pieces, private and public. Pretty much what you need to do annually anyways.

Comment: @dfd The developer.apple.com process is actually what I'm talking about. The problem is that they ask you to upload a CSR to create a new certificate. Am I just misunderstanding the process? I thought that an app needed to use the same private key for the lifetime of the app?

Comment: Ahhh... I think I know the issue. (I've do this once a year too - and only since 2016.) If you walk through things properly on the developer site, you'll get to a spot where they ask you to *"Upload a Certificate Signing Request"*... and there's a *"Learn more"* link ( https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devbfa00fef7 ) that explains how to use Keychain Access to generate this request. I think that link I posted will work for you, but I'm always confused because you aren't **really** upload anything - your's just **requesting** something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your p12 file and do the following

Generate the private key

```
openssl pkcs12 -in your.p12 -nodes -out private.key -nocerts
```

Generate the CSR

```
openssl req -new -key private.key -out request.csr
```

Then upload that to Apple

Comment: Note: This answer worked for me, but I haven't figured out if you actually need to generate the cert from the private key or if you can just upload a new private key to Apple.